# Given any sequence of interpolating nodes, can we find a continuous function $f$ whose interpolating polynomials doesn't converge to $f$ point-wise

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, approximation-theory, interpolation

Let $[a,b]$ be an interval in real line . Given any function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ and set $A \subseteq [a,b]$ of size $n+1$, there exists a unique polynomial $p_{f,A,n}(x)$ of degree $n$ such that $f(a)=p_{f,A,n}(a),\forall a\in A$. Such a polynomial is called the interpolating polynomial of $f$ with nodes $A$. Due to this, given $A\subseteq [a,b]$ with $n+1=|A|$, we can consider a linear map $X_{A,n} : C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$ such that $X_{A,n}(f)=p_{A,f,n}$ . Then $X_{A,n}$ is a continuous map and also a projection i.e. $X^2_{A,n}=X_{A,n}$. It can be shown that there is a constant $c$ such that $||X_{A,n}||_{\infty} \ge c \ln (n)$ for any set $A\subseteq [a,b]$ of size $n+1$, where $||.||_{\infty}$ is the $L^{\infty}$ operator norm induced from the $L^{\infty}$ norm on $C[a,b]$. Since $(C[a,b],||.||_{\infty})$ is a Banach space, it follows from Uniform boundedness principle, that given any sequence of subsets $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of $[a,b]$ with each $A_n$ having size $n+1$, $\exists f\in C[a,b]$ such that $||X_{A_n,n}(f) - f||_{\infty} $ does not converge to $0$.

This can be rephrased as: Given any sequence $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of  subsets of $[a,b]$, with each $A_n$ of size $n+1$, there exists a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that the sequence of interpolating polynomials $p_{f,A_n,n}(x)$ doesn't converge to $f$ uniformly on $C[a,b]$.

**My question** is the following: Given any sequence $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of  subsets of $[a,b]$, with each $A_n$ of size $n+1$, does there exist a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ such that the sequence of interpolating polynomials $p_{f,A_n,n}(x)$ doesn't converge to $f$ point-wise at atleast one point ?

Comment: Your final expression could be scanned as "does not (converge at at least one point)" (= diverges everywhere) or as "(does not converge,) at at least one point."

Comment: Indeed, often I need something like $\ \forall\,\exists(A\Rightarrow\forall\ldots)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result that you mention in the first part of your question is a classical result by Faber

> G. Faber, Uber die interpolatorsche Darstellung stetiger Funktionen, Jahresber. der deutschen Math. Verein. 23 (1914), 190-210.

Of course, this result does not exclude pointwise convergence. This question was negatively
answered by S. Bernstein in

> S. Bernstein, [Quelques remarques sur l'interpolation](https://eudml.org/doc/158778), Math. Ann. 79
>   (1918), 1-12; doi: [10.1007/BF01457173](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01457173).

For an arbitrary scheme $X=\cup_{n} A_{n}$ of points in $[-1,1]$, there exist a continuous function $f$ and a point $x_{0}$ in $[-1,1]$ such that
$$
 { \limsup _ { n \rightarrow \infty } } \left| L _ { n } \left( f, X , x _ { 0 } \right) \right| = \infty.
$$
The next natural question is the possibility of divergence on a set of positive measure. Such a result was obtained by Marcinkiewicz and Grunwald (independently) for the particular scheme $T$ of Chebyshev nodes :

There exists a function continuous $f$ such that
$$
{ \limsup _ { n \rightarrow \infty } } \left| L _ { n } \left( f, T , x \right) \right| = \infty \quad \text { for all } \quad x \in [ - 1,1 ].
$$
There is an explicit construction of such a function in the book by I.P. Natanson, Constructive Function Theory, Vol. 3, pp. 35-46.

P. Erdos made the conjecture that this negative result holds for an arbitrary scheme $X$ of points in $[-1,1]$. This was proved in

> P. Erdos and P. Vertesi, [On the almost everywhere divergence of
>   Lagrange interpolatory polynomials for arbitrary system of nodes](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1981-03.pdf), Acta
>   Math. Acad. Sci. Hungar. 36 (1980), 71-89 and 38 (1981), 263; doi: [10.1007/BF01897094](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01897094).

For any scheme of points $X$ in $[-1,1]$, there exists a function $f$ such that
$$
{ \limsup _ { n \rightarrow \infty } } \left| L _ { n } \left( f, T , x \right) \right| = \infty \quad \text {almost everywhere in} \quad x \in [ - 1,1 ],
$$
and the divergence set is of second category. Note that divergence everywhere is not possible just by considering a newtonian scheme i.e. a scheme that repeats points ($A_{n}\subset A_{n+1}$, $n\geq1$, in your notation).

A very nice book about classical interpolation of functions is

> Szabados, J., Vértesi, P., Interpolation of functions. World
>   Scientific Publishing Co., Teaneck, NJ, 1990.

Comment: could you please add a reference to that result by Marcinkiewiz and Grunwald ? Also ... has there been any other proofs of that result by Erdos and Vertesi ?

Comment: @user521337 Here are the references:
G. Griinwald, Uber Divergenzerscheinungen der Lagrangeschen
Interpolationspolynome stetiger Funktionen, Ann. of Math. 37
(1936), 908-918.

J. Marcinkiewicz, Sur la divergence des polynomes d'interpolation,
Acta Sci. Math. (Szeged) 8 (1937), 131-135.

I don't know of any other proof of the result by Erdos and Vertesi.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is certainly yes. But it may not be that pessimistic due to the following fact: for any continuous function, there always exists a configuration of interpolation points such that the Lagrangian interpolation converges.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide enough detail to be useful; please consider expanding on it.